# Why can't I have property of type Type in my model for Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, ef-fluent-api

I'm setting up a model for a project and everything works as expected, except for the change below. I thought it'd be neat to specify the type as `Type` instead of its description as `string`.

```
namespace DataBase.Entities
{
  public class Lock
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Occasion { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public Type Entity { get; set; }
    //public string Entity { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Guess what! EF didn't like it one bit. The error I get when adding an explicit migration then is as follows and I have no idea why.

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: entitySet

Most of the goolearching resulted in [people](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22680342/1525840) discovering that the POCO classes had some inheritance they forgot about. [Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215507/1525840) suggested to force re-enabled migrations. I don't have any inheritance at all in the model and forcing the migrations gave nothing but a recreated configuration file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would always store the assembly-qualified type name instead of the type itself.

A `Type` instance it's not just a name, but a lot of metadata that may be interesting during run-time, but it would be pointless to store (i.e. *serialize*) a type instance *as is*.

When you set the whole `Type` property get `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` property value:

```
instance.Type = typeof(X).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

And the code that should work with the whole type could call `Type.GetType(lock.Type)` to build a `Type` instance again.

Comment: I see your point and I find the suggestion well-motivated. Nevertheless, I'd like to know why I can't store the whole instance of type *System.Type* (not why I **shouldn't** but why I **can't**). Also, I'd love to see a bit of explanation how this issue can lead to that error message.

Comment: @konradviltersten basically EF is an ORM that is abstracting a relational database. So, if Type is a complex type, how do you expect EF to store a Type instance without serializing it? Does EF do it by default with reference types excluding strings?

Comment: Good point, mate. I was counting on EF to be using reflection to figure out all the public properties in all the entities that are in my context or are mentioned one way or the other by it. I guess it was a bit too much of a wishful hoping for automagical operations. Good explanation.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yeah... At the end of the day it's an OR/M. With NHibernate you have custom types that let  you customize things like that (serializing/deserializing complex types when the data is being written or read from/to the entity). BTW, AFAIK, Entity Framework has been always more limited and you would need to introduce ugly code or ugly workarounds to get this working...