# C# MVC Html.RenderAction("", "") Returning Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have an issue with areas of my project where I use `@Html.RenderAction();` I am confused as to what is causing this. These were working fine and the changes I have made before loading the project again, has nothing to do with these. I am getting an Inner exception Error

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet
```

These items are not null. I tried rebuilding but am still getting the issue. There is more than 1 area that this is faulting out. Where ever I use this it is happening and not on the same partial view. It is like it stopped working. I am going to save the project and reopen it and see if it goes away. I will post an update. Until them does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score -2):

Answer is here:
[Answer to issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680342/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-entityset)

I added this to one of my models

```
  public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
```

I needed to also add this: `[NotMapped]` Why it made my partials not work is beyond me!